# Ошибка при передаче структуры в функцию

Tags: c++, c

> error C4700: использована неинициализированная локальная переменная

```
struct BITMAPFILEHEADER
{
};
struct BITMAPINFOHEADER
{
};
struct RGBQUAD
{
};

void firstaction(BITMAPFILEHEADER, BITMAPINFOHEADER, RGBQUAD, FILE);
int main()
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER header;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
    RGBQUAD *pixels;
    firstaction(header, bmiHeader, *pixels, *pFile); // тут ошибка на первые 3 аргумента
}

void firstaction(BITMAPFILEHEADER header, BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader, RGBQUAD *pixels, FILE *pFile)
{
}
```

Кто сможет подсказать, в чем я ошибся?

Comment: В Вашем коде нет инициализации этих переменных. А по умолчанию за Вас ее с++ компилятор просто так не сделает.

Comment: BITMAPFILEHEADER header;
BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
RGBQUAD *pixels;

Разве это не инициализация?

Comment: Для `header` и `bmiHeader` не уверен, что говорят правила о конструкторе по умолчанию. А вот с `pixels` совершенно точно проблема: код

    RGBQUAD *pixels;

лишь объявляет **указатель** на `RGBQUAD`, но значение его произвольное. Вам нужно для начала выделить память под переменную типа `RGBQUAD`, и инициализировать указатель адресом этой переменной.

Comment: Помимо отсутствия инициализации я тут вижу такую проблему, как передача структур по значению. Кстати, все перечисленные структуры относятся к стандартным структурам WinAPI. И это сишные структуры, так что ни о каком конструкторе речи даже не идет.

Answer (score 1):

1. У вас ругается на переменную-указатель `*pixels`, который вы разыменовываете, не проинициализировав.
2. У вас используется две перегружженых функции `transaction`. Одна принимает  структуры в аргументе(она просто определена), вторая  - 2 структуры, 2 указателя на структуру.
   Судя по такому вызову функции функции `transaction`

   firstaction(header,bmiHeader,*pixels,*pFile);

   Вы вызываете первую реализацию функции `transaction`, вот эту

   void firstaction(BITMAPFILEHEADER, BITMAPINFOHEADER, RGBQUAD, FILE);

   Но она у вас не определена(только объявлена), в связи с этим линковщик будет ругаться, так как не найдена реализации функции.
3. Переменная `pFile` нигде не объявлена в вашем примере. Откуда она берется?

Если у вас проект написан в VisualStudio 2013, то чтобы отключить ошибку про инициализацию переменных, выполните

> В свойствах проекта - свойства конфигурации - С/С++ - создание кода -
>   проверка безопасности - Отключить проверку безопасности (/GS-)

Тогда у вас исчезнет пункт 1, но появиться проблема пункта 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
void firstaction(BITMAPFILEHEADER, BITMAPINFOHEADER, **`RGBQUAD`**, FILE);
void firstaction(BITMAPFILEHEADER header, BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader, **`RGBQUAD *`**pixels, FILE *pFile)
```

Comment: Хотел еще пояснить, C4700 - это вообще предупреждение, а не ошибка. Инициализировать переменные перед передачей в функцию это конечно Ваше дело :) У Вас скорее всего ошибка при линковке, так как я вижу что вы объявили функцию с 4 аргументами структуры, а в реализация функции две структуры и два указателя. Вот линковщик и ругается что не может найти реализацию объявленной функции.

Comment: А о чём ваш ответ, простите?

Кстати, использование неинициализированных переменных — UB, так что это не ошибка, а грубая ошибка.

Comment: Почему это "использование неинициализированных переменных является грубой ошибкой"? Обычно это предупреждение, т.е. компилятор сообщает, что возможно здесь скрывается ошибка. Я могу объявить переменную и ею инициализации генератора случайный чисел, типа такого:
int a;
srand(a);
здесь нет ошибки, и компилятор должен выдать только предупреждение.

Как я понял вопрос был связан почему данный код не компилится, а не почему он работает не верно, так как код в виде пустышек. И я сказал что инициализация не должна влиять на запуск кода, а правильно ли он будет работать это уже другой вопрос:)

Comment: >Почему это "использование неинициализированных переменных является грубой ошибкой"?  Обычно это предупреждение

Потому что это действительно грубая ошибка. Существуют не только ошибки компиляции. Есть также ошибки времени исполнения и ошибки логики. И те и другие гораздо хуже ошибок компиляции, потому что способны порушить программу.

Comment: @Gimka: Вы ошибаетесь, считая, что инициализация не влияет на работу программы: компилятор работает не построчно. Неинициализированная переменная по стандарту разрешает компилятору убрать код, содержащий её, или переписать произвольным образом.

Comment: Естественно, я про это и говорю. Так как компилятор не может проверить логику программы, поэтому при возникновении логической ошибки, он выдает предупреждение. А данный вопрос я расценил как про ошибку компиляции. В данном случаи ошибка на уровне линковки. Конструкторы вообще здесь не причем так как код на чистом си. И почему заминусовали ответ я не совсем понял :(
С чего Вы взяли, что я говорю что инициализация не влияет на работу программы?? Еще раз повторюсь это логическая ошибка (предупреждение). "...разрешает компилятору убрать код..." это здесь при чем? логику он все равно не меняет.

Comment: @Gimka:

> логику он все равно не меняет.

Неверно.

Вот такой код правильный:

    int x = 12345;
    int y = x - x;

А вот такой:

    int x;
    int y = x - x;

есть UB и имеет право отформатировать ваш винчестер. Подумайте об этом.

Comment: int x;
int y = x - x;
Если Вы хотите сделать именно это, то этот код является правильным, а в первом варианте наоборот может Вы допустили ошибку и случайно инициализировали. Все зависит от задач которые Вы преследуете, только по ним можно понять допустили вы ошибку или нет. В вопросе нет тела функции и описание структур тоже, и что хочет делать с ними автор мне лично не понятно, поэтому я и сказал с улыбкой что инициализация это Ваше дело. И что программа скорее всего не компилится из-за линковки объявленной функции, а не инициализации структур, как утверждает автор вопроса.